# How can I optimise this eloquent query to remove similar queries

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

An `appointment` can have many **statuses**, but the last created relation between `appointment` and `status` is the current status of the appointment. In my Appointment Datatable I want to display the related Agent, `InstructionType`, `SignUpCustomer` and the latest `status`. I want to `paginate` those records at `10` per page.

The relevant models are:

1. `Appointment` ( `belongsTo agent, instruction_type and sign_up_customer, belongsToMany status`)
2. `Agent`
3. `InstructionType`
4. `SignUpCustomer`

I have this query in my controller, which produces a result I send to Datatables.

```
$query = Appointment::with(['agent', 'instruction_type', 'sign_up_customer']);
            $query->with(['statuses' => function ($query) {
                $query->latest()->first();
            }]);
            $table = Datatables::of($query);
```

It is producing these two statements, the first one is fine, I don't need the last one. How can I optimise the query to remove that last statement?

```
select `statuses`.*, `appointment_status`.`appointment_id` as `pivot_appointment_id`, `appointment_status`.`status_id` as `pivot_status_id`, `appointment_status`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `appointment_status`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `statuses` inner join `appointment_status` on `statuses`.`id` = `appointment_status`.`status_id` where `appointment_status`.`appointment_id` in ('2') order by `created_at` desc limit 1

select `statuses`.*, `appointment_status`.`appointment_id` as `pivot_appointment_id`, `appointment_status`.`status_id` as `pivot_status_id`, `appointment_status`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `appointment_status`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at`, `appointment_status`.`appointment_id` as `pivot_appointment_id`, `appointment_status`.`status_id` as `pivot_status_id`, `appointment_status`.`created_at` as `pivot_created_at`, `appointment_status`.`updated_at` as `pivot_updated_at` from `statuses` inner join `appointment_status` on `statuses`.`id` = `appointment_status`.`status_id` where `appointment_status`.`appointment_id` in ('2') order by `created_at` desc limit 1
```

I've also tried this:

Model:

```
/**
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsToMany
     */
    public function statuses()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Status::class, 'appointment_status')->withTimestamps();
    }

    public function latestStatus()
    {
        return $this->statuses()->latest()->first();
    }
```

Controller:

```
$query = Appointment::with(['agent', 'instruction_type', 'sign_up_customer', 'latestStatus']);
            $table = Datatables::of($query);
```

But i get this error: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2445:
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addEagerConstraints()

Comment: Please  describe what your tables look like, what you want to get and what you tried. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Removing the $query->paginate(10) reduces the query to 8. However, I still have the two statements on the last lines above ^

Comment: If you're looking for performance you have to use RAW statements. Eloquent is not designed for performance.

Comment: Obviously removing the last statement from above would increase the performance. However, I'm just looking for a way to remove the last statement as it is not required.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do this using a local scope? https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#local-scopes

```
public function scopeLatest($query)
{
    return $query->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')->offset(0)->limit(1);
}
```

I've not actually done this before, but I see no reason why it wouldn't work (I also have no idea how optimised the resulting query would be).

Comment: I think your answer is a little irrelevant. The question is about how to optimize SQL-query. Not the code representation

Comment: Thanks for your opinion.